# Microsoft Reporting with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-reporting

I am developing an asp.net web application in which I am using LINQ  to SQL and I want to generate the Microsoft Reports with LINQ to SQL. Microsoft Reports DataSource is Dataset but I want to give IEnumberable or IQueryable as a DataSource because I have no Dataset. Is there any way or better solution to generate report with out a dataset.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Do you mean SSRS by Microsoft Reporting?

Comment: Me using Microsoft Reports of Visual studio 2010. I do not know about SSRS please tell me details of SSRS and the difference between the SSRS and Reports in VS 2010?

Comment: I think you are confusing a Shared Dataset, which SSRS uses, to allow a single dataset to be used by multiple reports, with the c# Dataset class.

SSRS Reports are not written in C# and as such have no (easy) access to .net Libraries.

What do you mean by Microsoft Reports 2010? If you are referring to the Report Viewer control, in VS2010, then you are actually referring to a Winforms control that allows you to view SSRS Reports in your native app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885185.aspx - Info on using the ReportViewer control

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that reporting really jives well with LINQ to SQL, since it's made to hit databases directly - I think you just have to bite the bullet and write your reports in SQL.